# Create grid image system with BootStrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I create this grid image system with bootstrap4 and css3?

[Check this link to see what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8QP3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide you here with the basic structure of HTML & CSS. You can customize styles according to your requirement. Ex:- Margins between grid items.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 bg-info">
<!-- Your 1st grid item releated elements here -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-secondary column">
          <!-- Your 2nd grid item releated elements here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-success column">
          <!-- Your 3rd grid item releated elements here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger column">
          <!-- Your 4th grid item releated elements here -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-warning column">
          <!-- Your 5th grid item releated elements here -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.column {
  padding-top: 25%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/yushanfernando/pen/GRWdQgd

Achieve all this using only the Bootstrap 4 grid system.

Let me know if you need further support.